# How to split a cell into columns so they have the same width as columns below them in a row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table, with two header cells. The second header cell needs to be split into two rows, with the bottom row split further into 6 columns (q1, q2, q3 etc). These columns should be the same width as those in the row below them. Please see the image and fiddle to see what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be great.
http://jsfiddle.net/CPSs9/

[image]

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/CPSs9/

My code is as follows:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
        <th width="120">Booboo</th>
        <th colspan="5">blah blah</th>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know about the rowspan and colspan attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy. All you need to do is use the `rowspan` attribute on the first `th` and add another row to the table. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/CPSs9/1/